# How to subset sparse matrix by value of a label list?

Tags: python, list, subset, sparse-matrix

I am using `fetch_20newsgroups_vectorized` data:

`import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups_vectorized`

`newsgroups = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all')
labels = newsgroups.target_names
news_data, news_labels = fetch_20newsgroups_vectorized(subset='all', normalize=False, return_X_y=True)
news_labels = [labels[i] for i in news_labels]` ### converting integer list to str list

when I try to subset matrix `news_data` based on groups of `news_label` (exstract all rows that have label i into a new matrix), it returns the same subset for each label level (there are 20 different levels and `news_data` is `csr_matrix`):

`for i in set(news_labels):
    print(i)
    subset = news_data[news_labels == i]`

How can I subset `news_data` for every level of `news_label`?

Answer (score 1):

I tried:

`for i in set(news_labels):
     indices = [element for element, x in enumerate(news_labels) if x == i]
     subset = news_data[indices]`

and it worked!